# Files missing from dropbox shared link

Tags: dropbox

I had a shared link of dropbox folder from someone but the earlier files are missing.
Is there a way to view earlier files.

Comment: Use the web interface. There should be an option to see file's history and within, deleted files.

Answer (score 0):

If the file was deleted in the last 30 days, then you can [view the deleted files and choose to restore it](https://www.dropbox.com/help/296/en)

[image]